# How to write gruntfile with express and angular

Tags: express, gruntjs, pug, grunt-usemin

I just started to learn Grunt, and encountered many problems,I use Express and Angular,My project directory as follows

```
|-server
  |-controllers
  |-routes
  |-models
  |-views
    |-users
      signin.jade
      signup.jade
    index.jade  //Index of server

|-public
  |-images
  |-javascripts
    |-controllers
    |-services
    |-directives
    app.coffee
  |-stylesheets
    app.scss
  |-views //Angularjs templates

gruntfile.js  
server.js
```

My `index.jade` is probably as follows

```
//- css, will use cdn files in production
link(href='bower_cmps/normalize-css/....')
link(href='bower_cmps/bootstrap/....')
link(href='stylesheets/app.css')

//- body
.container
  .row
    ...

//- scripts, will use cdn files in production
script(src='bower_cmps/jquery/...')
script(src='bower_cmps/angular/...')
script(src='bower_cmps/angular-ui-router/...')

script(src='javascripts/app.js')
script(src='javascripts/controllers/**.js')
script(src='javascripts/services/**.js')
```

I use `coffeescript` to write client side js, and use `scss` to write css

What was it like of `Grunt` dev configuration?

And how to use `usemin` to build production files?

Thanks for giving a hint

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/)? There's a bunch of Angular + Express generators, take a look at [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

Comment: Thanks, i have ideas now，but the `generator-angular-fullstack` have a bug, when i change the css file it's not reload.

Comment: you should making changes in `scss` file, once a change were detected, the code will be processed to `css`.

Comment: yse ,i know, but i have new [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184758/custome-usemin-flow-with-coffee-and-sass)